# My if statement is successfully submitting when it shouldn't

Tags: php, sql

I have a friend system, and to show an add as friend button, or cancel, or unfriend I am trying to do it like so:

When a user sends a friend request, it goes in to `friend_requests` and when they accept it, it deletes the row from friend_requests and adds 1 into to friends

What I am trying to do is, if the user_id isn't the same is the user id (session user) and there's no friend request or friends row then show an add me button, here's my query, but the code inside this keeps running when it shouldn't because the user has sent a request.

**friends table with sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `friends_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_friend` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friends_date_added` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `friends`
--

INSERT INTO `friends` (`friends_id`, `friends_user`, `friends_friend`, `friends_date_added`) VALUES
(15, 12, 3, '2015-08-27 05:07:36'),
(16, 3, 12, '2015-08-27 05:07:36');
```

**friend request with sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friend_request` (
  `friend_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_request_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_request_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_request_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `friend_request_enabled` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `friend_request_accepted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `friend_request_denied` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `friend_request`
--

INSERT INTO `friend_request` (`friend_request_id`, `friend_request_from`, `friend_request_to`, `friend_request_date`, `friend_request_enabled`, `friend_request_accepted`, `friend_request_denied`) VALUES
(38, 12, 11, '2015-08-27 05:07:52', 1, 0, 0),
(39, 3, 11, '2015-08-27 15:49:28', 1, 0, 0);
```

Here's my PHP and html with the if statement, to show if there's no friend request, and if they're not friends and if user->user_id isn't the session user show add me button, else if they're friends then show a unfirend button, or if it's the user who SENT the request show a cancel but or if it's the other user show an accept or reject button, all my code is there, it's just the if statement failing:

```
<!-- if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and they're not friends and no friend request exists, show an add as friend button !-->
                    <?php if($likes->user_id != Session::get('id') && $likes->friend_request_from != $likes->user_id && $likes->friend_request_to == Session::get('id') ||
                             $likes->user_id != Session::get('id') && $likes->friend_request_from != Session::get('id') && $likes->friend_request_to == $likes->user_id 
                             || $likes->friends_friend != $likes->user_id && $likes->friends_user != Session::get('id')): ?>                        
                        <a class="add_friend btn btn-success" id="<?php echo System::escape($likes->timeline_likes_id); ?>" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>friends/addfriend/<?php echo System::escape($likes->user_id).'/'.System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>
```

">

```
                <!-- if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and they are friends, show an unfriend button !-->
                <?php elseif($likes->user_id != Session::get('id') && isset($likes->friends_friend)): ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger unfriend_user" onclick="confirm('<?php echo System::translate("are you sure you want to unfriend this person?"); ?>')" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>friends/unfriend/<?php echo System::escape($likes->user_id).'/'.System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>"><?php echo System::translate("Unfriend User"); ?></a>
                <!-- end if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and no friend request exists but they are friends, show an unfriend button !-->

                <!-- if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and a friend request exists and they are the person who received the requests, show a reject or accept friend request buttons !-->
                <?php elseif($likes->user_id != Session::get('id') && isset($likes->friend_request_id) && $likes->friend_request_to == Session::get('id') && $likes->friend_request_from == $likes->user_id): ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" title="<?php echo System::translate("Accept friend request"); ?>" onclick="confirm('<?php echo system::translate("Are you sure you want to accept this friend request?"); ?>')"  href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>friends/accept_request/12/accept/<?php echo System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>"><?php echo System::translate("Accept"); ?></a> | 
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" title="<?php echo System::translate("Reject friend request"); ?>" onclick="confirm('<?php echo system::translate("Are you sure you want to reject this friend request?"); ?>')" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>friends/accept_request/12/reject/<?php echo System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>"><?php echo System::translate("Reject"); ?></a>
                <!-- end if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and a friend request exists and they are the person who received the requests, show a reject or accept friend request buttons !-->

                <!-- if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and a friend request exists and they are the person who sent the requests, show a cancel friend request button !-->
                <?php elseif($likes->user_id != Session::get('id') && isset($likes->friend_request_id) && $likes->friend_request_from == Session::get('id') && $likes->friend_request_to == $likes->user_id): ?>
                    <a id="<?php echo System::escape($likes->friend_request_id); ?>" class="btn btn-info cancel_friend_request" title="<?php echo System::translate("Cancel friend request"); ?>" onclick="confirm('<?php echo system::translate("Are you sure you want to cancel this friend request?"); ?>')" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>friends/cancel_request/<?php echo System::escape($likes->friend_request_id).'/'.System::escape(Session::get('token')); ?>"><?php echo System::translate("Cancel Request"); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- end if the like doesn't belong to the user who is logged in and a friend request exists and they are the person who sent the requests, show a cancel friend request button !-->
```

Here's a var dump from my main query:

```
object(stdClass)#8 (57) { ["timeline_likes_id"]=> string(2) "37" ["timeline_likes_user"]=> string(2) "11" ["timeline_likes_main_status"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_likes_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 18:15:03" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["user_username"]=> string(13) "blahahaha" ["user_email"]=> string(13) "lol@gmail.com" ["user_password"]=> string(60) "rerhjifgdkowergifedmfrgfm" ["user_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_firstname"]=> string(3) "LOL" ["user_surname"]=> string(7) "corkish" ["user_gender"]=> string(0) "" ["user_birthdate"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["user_country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["user_telephone"]=> string(5) "12345" ["user_mobile"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["user_contactemail"]=> string(18) "ncorkish@gmail.com" ["user_isadmin"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_staff"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_premium"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_registerdate"]=> string(19) "2015-07-21 19:33:20" ["user_introduction"]=> string(0) "" ["user_occupation"]=> string(18) "Working at present" ["user_available"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_relocate"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofactor"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofackey"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_privacy_telephone"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_mobile"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_email"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_friends"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_country"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_dob"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_available"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_forgot_email_code"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_emailverified"]=> string(10) "unverified" ["user_banned"]=> string(8) "unbanned" ["user_has_avatar"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_has_banner"]=> string(1) "0" ["timeline_status_id"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_status_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["timeline_status_privacy"]=> string(6) "public" ["timeline_status_type"]=> string(0) "" ["timeline_status_post"]=> string(5) "hello" ["timeline_status_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 18:10:51" ["timeline_status_enabled"]=> string(7) "enabled" ["friends_id"]=> NULL ["friends_user"]=> NULL ["friends_friend"]=> NULL ["friends_date_added"]=> NULL ["friend_request_id"]=> string(2) "38" ["friend_request_from"]=> string(2) "12" ["friend_request_to"]=> string(2) "11" ["friend_request_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-27 05:07:52" ["friend_request_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["friend_request_accepted"]=> string(1) "0" ["friend_request_denied"]=> string(1) "0" } Add as friend
    LOL 2 Corkish object(stdClass)#9 (57) { ["timeline_likes_id"]=> string(2) "39" ["timeline_likes_user"]=> string(2) "12" ["timeline_likes_main_status"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_likes_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 20:37:00" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "12" ["user_username"]=> string(13) "sirfaceless91" ["user_email"]=> string(14) "lol2@gmail.com" ["user_password"]=> string(60) "$" ["user_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_firstname"]=> string(5) "LOL 2" ["user_surname"]=> string(7) "corkish" ["user_gender"]=> string(0) "" ["user_birthdate"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["user_country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["user_telephone"]=> string(5) "12345" ["user_mobile"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["user_contactemail"]=> string(18) "ncorkish@gmail.com" ["user_isadmin"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_staff"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_premium"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_registerdate"]=> string(19) "2015-07-21 19:33:20" ["user_introduction"]=> string(0) "" ["user_occupation"]=> string(18) "Working at present" ["user_available"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_relocate"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofactor"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofackey"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_privacy_telephone"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_mobile"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_email"]=> string(7) "private" ["user_privacy_friends"]=> string(7) "private" ["user_privacy_country"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_dob"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_available"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_forgot_email_code"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_emailverified"]=> string(10) "unverified" ["user_banned"]=> string(8) "unbanned" ["user_has_avatar"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_has_banner"]=> string(1) "0" ["timeline_status_id"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_status_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["timeline_status_privacy"]=> string(6) "public" ["timeline_status_type"]=> string(0) "" ["timeline_status_post"]=> string(5) "hello" ["timeline_status_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 18:10:51" ["timeline_status_enabled"]=> string(7) "enabled" ["friends_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["friends_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["friends_friend"]=> string(2) "12" ["friends_date_added"]=> string(19) "2015-08-27 05:07:36" ["friend_request_id"]=> string(2) "38" ["friend_request_from"]=> string(2) "12" ["friend_request_to"]=> string(2) "11" ["friend_request_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-27 05:07:52" ["friend_request_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["friend_request_accepted"]=> string(1) "0" ["friend_request_denied"]=> string(1) "0" } Unfriend User
profile-image   Nath Corkish object(stdClass)#10 (57) { ["timeline_likes_id"]=> string(2) "40" ["timeline_likes_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["timeline_likes_main_status"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_likes_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 22:22:07" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["user_username"]=> string(13) "sirfaceless91" ["user_email"]=> string(23) "natecorkish91@gmail.com" ["user_password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$a.1vZUr5HU6vQhoUQG9YDupZaMFTgdvxSweEqiUCz3b9ivx2uOTcu" ["user_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_firstname"]=> string(4) "nath" ["user_surname"]=> string(7) "corkish" ["user_gender"]=> string(0) "" ["user_birthdate"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["user_country"]=> string(7) "Bahamas" ["user_telephone"]=> string(4) "2222" ["user_mobile"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["user_contactemail"]=> string(18) "ncorkish@gmail.com" ["user_isadmin"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_staff"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_premium"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_registerdate"]=> string(19) "2015-07-21 19:33:20" ["user_introduction"]=> string(61) "We specialse in finding ways for our users to socialise more." ["user_occupation"]=> string(16) "Looking for work" ["user_available"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_relocate"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofactor"]=> string(1) "0" ["user_twofackey"]=> string(16) "5GILYNBWBXVAUV3A" ["user_privacy_telephone"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_mobile"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_email"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_friends"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_country"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_dob"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_privacy_available"]=> string(6) "public" ["user_forgot_email_code"]=> string(32) "d71a30cb75faed7c48cba971cf934922" ["user_emailverified"]=> string(10) "unverified" ["user_banned"]=> string(8) "unbanned" ["user_has_avatar"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_has_banner"]=> string(1) "1" ["timeline_status_id"]=> string(2) "75" ["timeline_status_user"]=> string(1) "3" ["timeline_status_privacy"]=> string(6) "public" ["timeline_status_type"]=> string(0) "" ["timeline_status_post"]=> string(5) "hello" ["timeline_status_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-26 18:10:51" ["timeline_status_enabled"]=> string(7) "enabled" ["friends_id"]=> string(2) "15" ["friends_user"]=> string(2) "12" ["friends_friend"]=> string(1) "3" ["friends_date_added"]=> string(19) "2015-08-27 05:07:36" ["friend_request_id"]=> string(2) "39" ["friend_request_from"]=> string(1) "3" ["friend_request_to"]=> string(2) "11" ["friend_request_date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-27 15:49:28" ["friend_request_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["friend_request_accepted"]=> string(1) "0" ["friend_request_denied"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Comment: Please try to debug this by echo-ing the results from all those many variables and calls. Without knowing what those results are, no-one will be able to tell what's going wrong. (btw: is your code missing a `</a>` closing tag, right there where the format in your post breaks a bit?)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your logical OR's to AND's.
First of all, I can see what you where going for but you should be grouping your conditions in brackets but basically an OR will say ignore every condition up until now if this next condition is true.

It's hard to say what the result of this condition is:

```
$likes->friends_friend != $likes->user_id && $likes->friends_user != Session::get('id'))
```

but if it is ever true then the code will execute.

My guess is you only want the code to execute if all of the conditions there are true?

If so, try all AND's(&&). If not, just shoot me down and I will remove this post.

Comment: No need for shooting :) but `&&` takes preceedence over `||`, so that part will be safe... (see also [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)